# How long does it take to get from Gare du Nord to the Palace of Versailles, by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, paris, versailles

Hopefully a pretty straightforward question:

How long does it take to get from Gare du Nord to Versailles by public transport?

Quickest method would be best, and I'd assume that would be train but I'm not ruling out buses, etc.

Comment: I remember taking the metro and then RER line C and it took about 1 hour, I think. I never really tried it but I think you should forget about the bus if speed is the main criteria. Someone will probably post a more detailed study. Where do you want to go in Versailles? To the palace? [This webpage](http://www.paristoversailles.com/paris-to-versailles-by-train-rer/paris-versailles-by-train-rer/) might be useful. Also, be aware that Versailles is outside the city limits, you can't use the [usual metro tickets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_ticket_%22t%22).

Comment: Yeah, heading to see the palace.

Comment: There is a RER station not far from the palace, it's very easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RATP trip planner [gives 53mn](http://goo.gl/RKDReg) at 10 o'clock, november 28th, 2013.

The route is:

```
On foot         walk to Gare du Nord – RER

                from Gare du Nord
RER  Ligne B    direction Saint-Remy-les-Chevreuse
                up to Chatelet-Les Halles

On foot         connection

                from Chatelet-Les Halles
RER  Ligne A    direction Saint-Germain-en-Laye
                up to La Defense (Grande Arche)

On foot         connection

                from La Defense (Grande Arche)
SNCF 55         direction La Verriere
                up to Versailles-Chantiers
```

[Versailles-Chantiers](http://goo.gl/maps/BT9ut) is about 1km south-east from Château de Versailles.

To [Versailles-Château-Rive gauche](http://goo.gl/maps/irlGA), [this is 1h06](http://goo.gl/vDpJFz):

```
On foot         walk to Gare du Nord – RER

                from Gare du Nord
RER  Ligne B    direction Saint-Remy-les-Chevreuse
                up to Saint-Michel Notre-Dame

On foot         connection

                from Saint-Michel Notre-Dame
RER  Ligne C    direction Versailles-Rive Gauche
                up to Versailles-Rive Gauche
```

Comment: For the record we chose option B and it was very straightforward.  Fewer changes leaves fewer chances for things to go wrong, plus it also saves you a few minutes walk. :)

Comment: Versailles Chantiers is too far away for a casual walk, there is not much to see on the way if you take the straight road. It is better to take a bus from there to the castle (or, if you want to walk, go via the Cathédrale Saint-Louis)

Answer (score 8):

There are two main stations in Versaille, *Versailles - Château - Rive-Gauche* on the RER C, and *Versailles - Rive Droite* on regular suburban network. The Château stop is about a [5 minute walk to the entrance](http://www.paristoversailles.com/paris-to-versailles-by-train-rer/paris-versailles-by-train-rer/), which the Rive Droite one is closer to 10. There is also *Versailles - Chantiers* on the RER C and local lines, but that's the furthest.

I'd suggest you use [this Rome2Rio query](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Gare-de-Paris-Nord/Palace-of-Versailles) for a general idea, which should weight up the different walking options from the different stations. You're basically looking at about 50-60 minutes, depending on connections. Be aware that a regular Metro/RER ticket won't be valid as far out as Versailles, so you'll need to visit a ticket machine and buy a ticket for the journey - you can't just use a regular carnet one for example.

You can also use the [RATP trip planner](http://www.ratp.fr/itineraires/en/ratp/recherche-avancee) to check exact times, but you'll need to search for each of the 3 stations individually, then factor in the walking times by hand. You'll probably either want to take the RER B to Saint-Michel Notre-Dame and change to the RER C, or the RER E to Gare Saint-Lazare and change onto a local SNCF service to Versailles-Rive Droite. (Metro 4 to Montparnasse then local train to Versailles Chantiers suffers from poorer frequency, but is a tiny bit faster if it works out)

Comment: @dlanod: using the RATP Trip planner, no need to do it in 3 parts: you just choose: "gare du nord" and "versailles", then when it asks further explanation : "Paris-Nord (Gare), Paris" for origin and "Versailles-Rive Gauche (RER), Versailles" for destination. And it gives all infos out. It takes 1h approximately (but this depends on the departure time). below will be the changes, and the map. You can also click "Show the detail of the route" to get further details of each parts of the trip. and in-between there are 2 "leave later" "arrive earlier" buttons to chose another departure/arrival time

Answer (score 2):

According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Gare-du-Nord-Paris-France/Versailles) 33 minutes.

Comment: That's if you already have a ticket, know your way and all the connections work out perfectly. I wouldn't count on it, certainly not if I need to catch a train. (+1 for the very neat map and comparison)

Comment: @Annoyed I agree in general, however I kind of feel that in this case the estimate is quite accurate. Metro 4 has high frequency

Comment: the time doesn't take at all in accoutn the waiting time (one of the 33mn trip uses a RER line which has a frequency of 20mn...). The RATP site is much more precise (*if* no problem occurs on the lines, which unfortunately happens. I believe the RATP site adds a few minutes in between each "hop" to try to counter that)

Comment: 33 minutes? That's unrealistic. You'd have to know the way well, rush in the corridors, and be exactly on time for one of the few non-stop trains from Montparnasse (about one per hour off-peak, I think). And that gets you to Versailles Chantiers, which is about 10 minutes' walk further from the Palace than Rive Gauche.